# Rtabmap won't start use frames

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason rtabmap won't use frames anymore.
After the line:

> rtabmap 0.11.8 started...

Nothing more follows. I am using freenect_launch freenect-registered-xyzrgb.launch but also freenect_launch freenect.launch will not work currently.
For the launch file of rtabmap I am using the following:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Kinect cloud to laser scan -->
    <node pkg="depthimage_to_laserscan" type="depthimage_to_laserscan" name="depthimage_to_laserscan">
      <remap from="image"     to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="camera_info" to="/camera/depth_registered/camera_info"/>
      <remap from="scan" to="/base_scan"/>
      <param name="range_max" type="double" value="4"/>
    </node>

  <!-- SLAM -->
  <group ns="rtabmap">
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
          <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_footprint"/>

          <param name="subscribe_depth" type="bool" value="true"/>
          <param name="subscribe_scan" type="bool" value="true"/>

          <remap from="odom" to="/base_controller/odom"/>
          <remap from="scan" to="/base_scan"/>

          <remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/>
          <remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
          <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>

          <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="10"/>

          <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
          <param name="RGBD/ProximityBySpace"     type="string" value="false"/>
          <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate"        type="string" value="0.01"/>
          <param name="RGBD/LinearUpdate"         type="string" value="0.01"/>
          <param name="RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd" type="string" value="false"/>
          <param name="Optimizer/Slam2D"          type="string" value="true"/>
          <param name="Reg/Strategy"              type="string" value="1"/> <!-- 1=ICP -->
          <param name="Reg/Force3DoF"             type="string" value="true"/>
          <param name="Vis/MaxDepth"              type="string" value="4.0"/>
          <param name="Vis/MinInliers"            type="string" value="5"/>
          <param name="Vis/InlierDistance"        type="string" value="0.05"/>
          <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr"           type="string" value="700"/>
          <param name="Mem/RehearsalSimilarity"   type="string" value="0.45"/>
          <param name="Icp/CorrespondenceRatio"   type="string" value="0.5"/>
          <param name="Vis/MaxFeatures"           type="string" value="500"/>
          <param name="Mem/ImagePreDecimation"    type="string" value="2"/>
          <param name="Mem/ImagePostDecimation"   type="string" value="2"/>
          <param name="Kp/DetectorStrategy"       type="string" value="6"/>
          <param name="OdomF2M/MaxSize"           type="string" value="1000"/>
          <param name="Odom/ImageDecimation"      type="string" value="2"/>
          <param name="delete_db_on_start"        type="string" value="true"/>
    </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

When using the debugger it says:

```
Connection::drop(2)
TCP socket [14] closed
Connection::drop(0)
Connection::drop(2)
Connection::drop(2)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246931/rtabmap-won%27t-start-use-frames/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

rtabmap is subscribed to 5 topics:

```
<remap from="odom" to="/base_controller/odom"/>
<remap from="scan" to="/base_scan"/>
<remap from="rgb/image" to="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/>
<remap from="depth/image" to="/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"/>
<remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
```

If any of these is not published, the callback won't be called. Is `/base_controller/odom` published?

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0